# Is there a way of identifying base layers for docker so I can reuse them?

Tags: docker

I have a complex docker image that includes linux plus a number of packages. This uses several Gb for the image and each instance.

Now I want to create a simpler image on the same server but still need linux. If I use the same base layer rather than a completely different version this would presumably save space. But how do I know what the base layer is?

I have tried docker history but the base layer image id I can't find; and the others are all listed as "missing".

Comment: Do you have the original Dockerfile and context used to create the image? If so, using that dockerfile to recreate a smaller image should ideally recreate the same layers and you should be able to use them correctly.